# Itemize equation with bullets

Tags: equations, itemize

I am trying to place an equation ''inside'' itemize environment. 
Basically I would like to avoid using `\begin{cases}` and just represent the equation by using itemize (one bullet for each case)
Moreover I think it might look better if the text after ''if'' would be aligned with one another. Does anyone know how to approach the problem?

```
$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\bullet\Bigl\{1,\theta,\frac{\theta^2}{k}\Bigr\}\;\;\text{if}\;\;m^2\not\equiv 1 \pmod 9 \vspace{3mm}\\
\bullet\Bigl\{1,\theta,\frac{k^2\pm k^2 \theta+\theta^2}{3k}\Bigr\}\;\;\text{if}\;\;m\pm \equiv 1 \pmod 9
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$
```

and the output looks like this
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is use of `array`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{array}{lll}
\bullet& \Bigl \{1,\theta,\frac{\theta^2}{k}\Bigr\}\;\;& \text{if}\;\;m^2\not\equiv 1 \pmod 9 \vspace{3mm}\\
\bullet& \Bigl \{1,\theta,\frac{k^2\pm k^2 \theta+\theta^2}{3k}\Bigr\}\;\;& \text{if}\;\;m\pm \equiv 1 \pmod 9
\end{array}
\right .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all those `\;\;` by using `~`
Also `\Big{` can be replaced
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \bullet \left\{1,\theta,\frac{\theta^2}{k}\right\} & \text{if~} m^2\not\equiv 1 \pmod 9 \vspace{3mm} \\
        \bullet \left\{1,\theta,\frac{k^2\pm k^2 \theta+\theta^2}{3k}\right\} & \text{if~} m\pm\equiv 1 \pmod 9
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you remove **bullets**:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a tabular stack (I started with the guts of Jesse's answer).  Vertical spacing between equations is adjusted with the optional argument to `tabularstackanchor`, while horizontal gaps between columns can be set with `\setstacktabulargap{length}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\stackMath
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\tabularstackanchor[6pt]{llll}{
\bullet&\Bigl \{1,\theta,\frac{\theta^2}{k}\Bigr\}& \text{if~}m^2\not\equiv1&\pmod 9
}{
\bullet&\Bigl \{1,\theta,\frac{k^2\pm k^2 \theta+\theta^2}{3k}\Bigr\}&
  \text{if~}m\pm\equiv1 &\pmod 9
}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]